# How to read the thumb_image column in the WhatsApp Messengers SQLite3 database?

Tags: database, sqlite, whatsapp

Android WhatsApp messenger uses a sqlite3 database. One of the columns is "thumb_image". I believe this is a "Java Serialized Object" (the hex of the first two bytes is "AC ED") but I am uncertain how to completely read the contents of the file.

I've got file I speak of above ("Java Serialized Object") by doing the following:

1. Use Sqlite3 to dump the database to a file.
2. Decode the hex string in the thumb_image column for any message (row) which has a media object.

   `echo '<thumb_image_column_hex_data>' | xxd -r -p > jdefile`

I guess my question could have been how to read a Java Serialized Object but I am uncertain it indeed is such an object. If it indeed is such an Object is there a way to read data from it. The ASCII of the jdefile shows that it has information like the path to the media object in the respective WhatsApp Message.

[TOOL] Whatsapp Xtract from xda-developers does not help to give me this data either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok figured out how to do this (This a quick and dirty method).

1. Download and Install Java SDK (set Path and classpath variables accordingly)
2. Dump the WhatsApp database:

   ```
   sqlite3 msgstore.db
   .output dump.sql
   .dump
   .exit
   ```
3. Find the `thumb_image` column in the dump.sql file you want to read/modify. eg:

   ```
   X'ACED0......
   ```
4. Write the above data to binary format using the command below (note: use the full data you get from your data.sql file in place of `ACED000...`:

   ```
   echo 'ACED000...' | xxd -r -p > thumb.ser
   ```
5. Make the following java files using:

   - MediaData.java:

     ```
     package com.whatsapp;

     import java.io.File;
     import java.io.Serializable;

     public class MediaData implements Serializable {
     static final long serialVersionUID = -3211751283609594L;

     boolean autodownloadRetryEnabled;
     int faceX;
     int faceY;
     long fileSize;
     long progress;
     boolean transcoded;
     boolean transferred;
     long trimFrom;
     long trimTo;
     File file;

     public boolean get1() {
         return autodownloadRetryEnabled;
     }

     public int get2() {
         return faceX;
     }

     public int get3() {
         return faceY;
     }

     public long get4() {
         return fileSize;
     }

     public long get5() {
         return progress;
     }

     public boolean get6() {
         return transcoded;
     }

     public boolean get7() {
         return transferred;
     }

     public long get8() {
         return trimFrom;
     }

     public long get9() {
         return trimTo;
     }

     public File get10() {
         return file;
     }
     }
     ```
   - readdata.java:

     ```
     import java.io.FileInputStream;
     import java.io.FileOutputStream;
     import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
     import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

     import com.whatsapp.MediaData;

     public class readdata {

         public static void main(String[] args) {

             try {
                 //Create Mediadata object
                 MediaData md;

                 //Read bianry data
                 ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("thumb.ser"));

                 //Set Mediadata object "md" to data ready from binary file using Mediadata cast
                 md = (MediaData) oin.readObject();

                 //Print Existing Values
                 System.out.println(md.get1());
                 System.out.println(md.get2());
                 System.out.println(md.get3());
                 System.out.println(md.get4());
                 System.out.println(md.get5());
                 System.out.println(md.get6());
                 System.out.println(md.get7());
                 System.out.println(md.get8());
                 System.out.println(md.get9());
                 System.out.println(md.get10());

                 //Data can be modified and then written out to serialized file again:          

                 //Write data to new binary file
                 ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("thumb.mod.ser"));

                 oout.writeObject(md);
                 oout.flush();
                 oout.close();

             }

             catch (Exception exc)
             {
                 exc.printStackTrace();
             }
         }    
     }
     ```
6. Now compile java code and execute:

   ```
   $ javac -d . MediaData.java && javac readdata.java && java readdata

   true
   422
   128
   58716
   100
   false
   true
   0
   0
   \storage\emulated\0\WhatsApp\Media\WhatsApp Images\IMG-20151111-WA0026.jpg
   ```

That should print the information in the `thumb.ser` file.

***Note:***
jdeserialize was used to determine/reverse engineer the class definition used in Mediadata.java

***References:***

1. https://jdeserialize.googlecode.com/files/jdeserialize-1.2.jar
2. https://code.google.com/p/jdeserialize/
3. https://community.oracle.com/thread/2113555
4. https://github.com/jberkel/whassup/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/jberkel/whassup/model/Media.java
5. https://github.com/jberkel/whassup/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/whatsapp/MediaData.java